# How can I make list-in-list sentence by sentence out of pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, sentence

I currently 'pd.read_csv'-ed and got something like this:

```
  sent_id  word      pos_tag
0  1        Stack     noun
1  1        overflow  noun
2  1        is        verb
3  1        great     adjective
4  2        Luv       verb
5  2        you       pronoun
6  2        guys      noun
7  3        Thank     verb
8  3        you       pronoun
```

I want to return things like these:

```
[[Stack, overflow, is, great], [Luv, you, guys], [Thank, you], ...]
[[(Stack, noun), (overflow, noun), (is, verb), (great, adjective)], ...]
```

Please help me, thank you.

Comment: `df.groupby('sent_id')['word'].apply(list)`   This should give you an idea

Comment: `df.groupby('sent_id')['word'].agg(list).tolist()` works for me

Comment: Thank you very much for a concise code!